# Weird error in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following code,

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\abc.txt")
```

but it is raising this in while compile

> Error 1   Friend access was granted to 'System,
>   PublicKey=00000000000000000400000000000000', but the output assembly
>   is named 'System, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Try adding a reference to 'System,
>   PublicKey=00000000000000000400000000000000' or changing the output
>   assembly name to match.   c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll    System

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with you project setup. Friend access is granted using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute. Are you using this attribute in your code? Does this error occur when you create a new .NET 4.0 class library project and start using TextWriter/StreamWriter?

Comment: Is this line of code relavent to the problem?

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes, once this line is removed the problem is gone

Comment: @Kieren: Isn't it abit too much?

Comment: 1) ask for help, 2) ignore help ?

Comment: @Kieren: Cmon, I am just looking for a softer solution than go straight to reinstall .NET Framework

Comment: Maybe that's why it wasn't working?  "I have a problem".. "I don't think it's worth trying X" .. sometimes that's a naive attitude :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shot in the dark...

Have you called your project "System", or do you have "System" in your namepsace? If you have .Net will get terribly confused as there is already something called `System.dll`. Call your project something else, so the output dll is named differently.

Comment: +1 First thing that came to me too, that FQN of System looks very suspicious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different versions of same DLLs? In the past I got a similar exception when I installed two versions of Crystal Report and used its APIs in my code.

Comment: doubt so, plus it's just the System.IO, the VS.NET 2010 come with .NET 3.5 anyway